# Client location alert for nearest employer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location, alert

Im in need of some help, im Trying to figure out how im going to implement this into my android application.

User fills in a text form presses a button, his location and message is sent to the nearest employee, the employee can accept or decline and the next closest person can choose to accept or decline till the client is helped.

Really don't know how to do this if anyone can point me in the right direction i Will appreciate it.

Regards,
Faz

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you have done so far? So we have a point where we can start to help you

Comment: @Blobonat To be honest... I really dont know where to begin with this... i have created everything around it, but this map part is boggling my mind... trying to find out myself where to start with this.

Comment: I do not develop for android so I can't really help you with big knowledge, but I would do it like: 1. Use a GPS API for Android to track customers location; 2. When the user presses the button he startes a request to all employee phones which now send their location to a server; 3. at the server you make a list where you calculate the distances between employees and customer; 4. now go through the list and send a request to each employee until one employee accepted. I'll hope that this helps you a little bit :)

Comment: Use the android GPS API, get your location and get the locations of all the other users, when you click the button, get all of their locations and calculate the difference between their position and yours, then pick the shortest one.
you can use http to ask for their positions